# Mysql WHERE NOT EXISTS (query) OR (query)

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to write one query that checks if either subqueries are correct as opposed to one?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM    eotm_dyn d
        WHERE   d.employeeID = e.id
        ) OR (select * FROM table c WHERE c.employeeID = e.id)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the employees where they don't have any records in eotm_dyn or table?

Comment: The expression "checks if either subqueries are correct as opposed to one" does not make sense in English.  If either subquery is correct, then one is.

Comment: two left joins + check for null?

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little hard to understand but I'm guessing this is what You are asking for.
It will return records from `employees` table that doesn't have any related rows in tables `eotm_dyn` and `table`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE  e.id NOT IN
    (
        (SELECT  employeeID 
        FROM    eotm_dyn)
     UNION
        (SELECT employeeID 
        FROM table)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just change that `OR` condition to another `EXISTS` expression:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
           (
             SELECT  null 
             FROM    eotm_dyn d
             WHERE   d.employeeID = e.id
           ) 
    AND NOT EXISTS
           (
             select null
             FROM   table c
             WHERE  c.employeeID = e.id
           )
```

Also guessing as to your intention.  This will check that the record does not exist for **BOTH** sub-queries.  I'm not sure what you mean if you mean to check one **OR** the other.

UPDATE:  Trying to imagine again, perhaps you meant to do a `OR EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
           (
             SELECT  null 
             FROM    eotm_dyn d
             WHERE   d.employeeID = e.id
           ) 
     OR EXISTS
           (
             select null
             FROM   table c
             WHERE  c.employeeID = e.id
           )
```

This will find records in `employees` that are either **NOT** in `eotm_dyn` or **ARE** in `table`.